# Publishing a WPF application in VS 2008 triggers "the server unexpectedly closed the connection"

Tags: .net, wpf, visual-studio-2008, iis-6

I'm using Windows Server, IIS 6.0 and VS 2008 Professional. When I click "Publish WPF application" I get "the server unexpectedly closed the connection". Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You've got rights to write to the IIS app folder?

As an alternative you could publish using the filesystem \\server\c$\inetpub\etc